# Find optimal matrix to maximize the expected expression

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am interested of the following function with $Q$. 
$$f(Q)=h^TQh-\frac{1}{(h^TQh+1)^2}-g^TQg+\frac{1}{(1+g^TQg)^2}$$
where $h$ and $g$ are both given $N\times 1$ vectors. And $Q$ is $N \times N$ positive definite matrix.
I want to find the optimal $Q$ that achieve the maximum. That is:
$$Q_0=\arg \max_{Q} f(Q)$$ where $Q$ should be positive definite and subject to $tr(Q) \leq P$.

I want to get an analytical solution. What are my options in terms of solutions to this problem?

---

The origin problem is hard to get an analytical solution. So I put more constraint on $Q$ to simplify the problem.

We assume that the rank of $Q$ is one, which means that Q can be represented as $Pqq^T$. Here I want to figure out the optimal $q$ that maximize the origin problem.

In order to make my statement more clear, I rewrite the refined problem here.
$$q_0=\arg \max_q P {\left| h^Tq \right|}^2-\frac{1}{(P {\left| h^Tq \right|}^2+1)^2}- P {\left| g^Tq \right|}^2+\frac{1}{(P {\left| g^Tq \right|}^2+1)^2}$$
where $q$ is subject to $|q|=1$.

Thank you ^.^

Comment: You could construct $Q$ such that $g$ corresponds to the eigenvector of the smallest eigenvalue which you can choose to be arbitrarily small, and then the last term can be arbitrarily large.. (unless $h=g$)

Comment: @m.a. Sorry..There is some mistakes about my function. I have refined it.

Comment: If you restrict $Q$ to being positive definite with $\text{tr}(Q) \le P$, then the feasible region of matrices $Q$ is bounded but not closed, since there are positive definite matrices $Q$ which are arbitrarily close to a non-negative definite matrix. Therefore, it is possible that $f(Q)$ can get arbitrarily close to some value $f_0$, but can't attain this value.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 well..I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain it more?

Comment: @m.a. both $g$ and $P$ are arbitrarily chosen. And I am not sure that the refined function can be driven arbitrarily high because $Q$ is positive definite and the last term is bounded above by 1.

Comment: @NalRa I withdrew my comment. I misread this time!